# How to port android to run on a lg gt350 mobile that meets the android minimum device requirements

Tags: android, mobile, operating-system, port

i have searched all over the net to find any ports of Android to lg gt350i, but i found none , so i decided to build it myself , is it possible to build android for lg gt350i? how should i flash it into my phone?

Comment: You'll need android-friendly drivers for all your hardware.  Try asking on the android-porting google group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the [LG GT350i](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_town_gt350-3135.php) is listed as running the [LG OS](http://www.globalteleshop.com/product.php?id_product=247), not Android.

Your best bet IMHO is to inquire at one of the [XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=564).